# How do I load the address from CiviCRM into a commerce billing profile?

Tags: civicrm

I have a commerce store linked with CiviCRM. I'd like that customers only enter their address once, in the CiviCRM contact profile.

How do I load the profile to copy to a Commerce billing profile?

I have installed *civicrm_entity*.

These are the ways I can think of doing it:

1. Load the CiviCRM session.

How do I get my module to load CiviCRM classes? I see that *civicrm_entity* loads CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch? Or load CRM_Core_Session. We are already 'logged in' to CiviCRM so we should be able to load that session?

I'm getting class not found errors.

2. Load the entity.

   $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('profile')->load($account->id());
   $profile_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('profile');
   $civicrm_contect = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('civicrm_contact')
   ->loadByProperties();

Properties? In the past we used email. I can't see anything in my *external_identifier* field, so which is best?

3. API

This is the way we did it in the past.

If I load the CiviCRM details I have my event *OrderEvents::ORDER_PAID* running where I can set the billing profile details

Comment: I would encourage you to post your question at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com if you've not already done so. Also the CiviCRM chat forum at https://chat.civicrm.org is likely to be helpful.

Comment: we have used Drupal Rules successfully in the past for this

Comment: True - so have we. Rules completely breaking 'context' and block mapping on d9. Looks like events replace rules in commerce-2.